# Find exact roots of $\sqrt{4+x}+\sqrt{1-x}=x^2+3$

Tags: roots, common-root

I have some difficulties with this problem:

Find exact roots of $\sqrt{4+x}+\sqrt{1-x}=x^2+3$

I know that we can square both side 2 times to have 8th degree equation with x, but I can't find the excat form of roots. Is there another way to solve this problem (without square 2 times) or find the exact roots? Thank you so much

Comment: Well, notice that $x=0$ is one of the two solutions. The other one is $x\approx-0.221456$.

Comment: @JanEerland yeah, I know it, but I need to find the exact form of -0.221456 (it's the root of a 7th degree so I can't find it)

Comment: What is the polynomial you found?

Comment: @Doug I got $x^7 + 12 x^5 + 44 x^3 + 52 x + 12$

Comment: It is likely that this polynomial is not solvable by radicals, unless you can reduce it to a quartic or lower, by the Abel-Ruffini theorem. It is vaguely possible that it *is*
 solvable, but the procedure to solve solvable an irreducible septic polynomial would be unbelievably nightmarish (the analogue for a quintic is apparently three pages long!) so I expect you need to solve it *another way*

Comment: @FShrike yeah, it's true. I think it's another way too but I can't find it

Comment: I'd be curious to know if there is a test to determine if a polynomial has an algebraic root.

Comment: @Doug There always is, for any degree polynomial, in principle, a test for solvability (or partial solvability). However, devising a test like this in general is impossible. It is difficult enough for $n=5$, never mind $n=7$. You'd need to classify all solvable subgroups of $S_n$ and find resolvents for each one...

Comment: @FShrike Maybe we are all looking for a way to solve the question.  But if we knew the source of the problem, it would be worth the effort.  That is, no algebraic method can help if the polynomial is not already solvable.  Is not it?

Comment: For what it's worth, Wolfram Alpha says the exact non-zero real solution to the original equation is "root of $x^7+12x^5+44x^3+52x+12$ near $x=-0.221456$". ([Link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sqrt%284%2Bx%29%2Bsqrt%281-x%29%3Dx%5E2%2B3%2C+-4%3Cx%3C1), click "Exact forms".) So it can't find any simplifications either.

Comment: My two cents worth: I got the same polynomial as @Jnote. I'm intrigued by this problem, but I'm at a loss as to what to do at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

The Galois group of $x^7+12x^5+44x^3+52x+12$ is $S_7$, which is not solvable.

Edit: Possibly the question is

Find exact roots of $\sqrt{4+x}+\sqrt{1-x}=\sqrt{x^2+3}$

This is equivalent to finding the roots of $x^4+12x-12$, which has solvable Galois group $S_4$.

Comment: + Thus, no "tricks" can solve this question :D

Comment: Is there an input for WA, such that we  can see,  any polynomial is solvable or not by radicals?Is there such an input?

Comment: @User There is one for irreducible polynomials, yes. But I don't know about WA.